# use sed to replace string which has non alpha numeric char before and after it

Tags: linux, string, bash, sed

I want to use sed command, in order to replace specific string with other string.
However, I want to skip the string occurrences which the last char before them or the first char after them is alphanumeric.
This means I want to replace these string only if it has non alpha numeric char before and after it.

I tried many ways and search the web, without result.

For example:
The string is:

```
aaaBCD] BCD1 [BCD] BCD.
```

If I'll try to swap `BCD` with `BBB`, I want only the last two `BCD` will be replaced.

Comment: I've find another option:
`printf ";BCD,\n" | sed "s/[^[:alnum:]_]BCD[^[:alnum:]_]/BBB/g"`
This seems to recognize correct if the string should be replaced, however it removes the start and end characters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\<` and `\>` as anchors:

```
sed 's/\<BCD\>/BBB/'
```

This, however, does not take care of underscores. So augment it to

```
sed -e 's/\<BCD\>/BBB/' -e 's/_BCD\>/_BBB/' -e 's/\<BCD_/BBB_/' -e 's/_BCD_/_BBB_/'
```

**Edit:** You can actually combine all command into a single one, using the **OR** of extended regular expressions, as well as pattern substrings like Jay jargot did in his answer. Extended regex is enabled with the **-E** switch to sed:

```
sed -E 's/((_|\<))BCD((_|\>))/\1BBB\3/g'
```

By the way, here you can find nice tutorials on sed, awk, regular expressions...

> http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/

Comment: It seems that this don't handle the underscore correct.
This command:
`printf "_BCD,\n" | sed -e 's/\<BCD\>/BBB/' -e 's/_BCD\>/_BBB/' -e 's/\<BCD_/BBB_/' -e 's/_BCD_/_BBB_/'`

Does replaces the BCD and returns ";BBB_".

Comment: @user28282 Your command returns `_BBB,` in my bash.

Answer (score 0):

`[:alnum:]` stands for alpha numerical, thus `[^[:alnum:]]` can be used for non alpha numerical char.

Give try to this:

```
printf '%s\n' 'aaaBCD] BCD1 [BCD] BCD' |\
  sed 's/^BCD$/BBB/ ; s/^BCD\([^[:alnum:]]\)/BBB\1/ ; s/\([^[:alnum:]]\)BCD\([^[:alnum:]]\)/\1BBB\2/g ; s/\([^[:alnum:]]\)BCD$/\1BBB/'
```

**Output**

```
aaaBCD] BCD1 [BBB] BBB
```

Comment: You can actually reduce it to a single command by using extended regex: `sed -E "s/((^|[^[:alnum:]]))BCD(($|[^[:alnum:]]))/\1BBB\3/"`

Comment: @StefanHamcke: this is true !